# $http.get() is not reaching web api controller..resource not found

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a web api controller from angular and I receive resource not found exception. The call is not reaching my controller. Thanks. Here is my code

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/triangle")]
        public string Get()
        {

            return "Please enter all sides.";
        }



$http.get("/api/Triangle").success(function (data) {

            $scope.resulttriangle = JSON.parse(data);

        });

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

Comment: changing application_start() worked.

Comment: "api/triangle"  and "/api/triangle"  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo. You've defined your route as `"api/triangle` and you are trying `"api/Triangle`.